# Google Geocoding / Airport Info

Tags: javascript, google-maps, rest, geocoding

I've been looking for list of types of queries that geocoder supports beyond regular address geocoding. At this time I need to query Google for airport locations.

I have stumbled upon [this IBM document](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails05208/index.html) but it mentions no place where I can get up-to-date list of allowed and useful Google geocoder query parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also look at the Yahoo APIs. I tend to find them a bit more hacker-friendly than Google's APIs.  Specifically, look at http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html for geocoding with Yahoo.

Answer (score 2):

You can also geocode airport codes:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=PDX&output=csv&sensor=false
```

Where PDX is the airport code for Portland, OR

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with all the airport IATA codes.

Comment: One possible consideration is the data suppliers that Google bought the database from. Some suppliers might consider IATA codes to be addresses to be included in the database and other suppliers might not. The Geocoder is only supposed to geocode addresses. Perhaps Google AJAX Local Search might have more airport codes, in situations where the data supplier considered IATA codes to be business names rather than addresses. Obviously, IATA codes in countries that are not yet supported are unlikely to work.

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=PDX&output=csv&sensor=false API call will not support all IATA airport codes, for example: SIN is the IATA code for Singapore Airport but this API returns http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=SIN&output=csv&sensor=false Latitude:         25.1721091
Longitude:        -107.4795173
Full address:     Sinaloa, Mexico
City:             
State/province:   Sinaloa
Postal code:      
Country:          Mexico
Google map:       http://maps.google.com/maps?q=25.1721091,-107.4795173

Answer (score 1):

You can do geocoding with the Google Maps API using the following HTTP request:

Simple CSV:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=London+Heathrow+Airport&output=csv&sensor=false
```

More Complex XML:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=London+Heathrow+Airport&output=xml&sensor=false
```

Simply change the "q" parameter with your Airport.